# How do I activate the level selection menu without encountering Mask Koopas?

Tags: super-mario-advance-2

In *Super Mario World: Super Mario Advance 2* (GBA), in order to select levels from the L menu, one has to finish all 96 levels is what I read somewhere. So I downloaded a [save file from this site](https://gbatemp.net/download/super-mario-advance-2-super-mario-world-us.36144/).

However, I see what is known as "Masked Koopas" instead of regular ones in all levels. How do I have the selection menu working and also avoid Mask Koopas?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Super Mario Wiki,

> After the player beats every special level in the Special Zone, a game aesthetic change called Fall occurs, where the world map obtains a different palette and some enemies get their sprites changed. Once Fall is activated, these changes cannot be reversed unless the save file is deleted and a new game is started.

So, it sounds like you are stuck with the new sprites, unless you start over.

https://www.mariowiki.com/Fall